# incorrect time in the sentence?

Tags: backshifting

This sentence is from some game manual:

> For example, if a player **started** a battle with a “XYZ” Order and then **attempts** diplomacy with the card bonus, he must retreat if he draws a "HJK"

Is that sentence correct?? Or should it be:

> For example, if a player **starts** a battle with a “XYZ” Order and then attempts diplomacy with the card bonus, he must retreat if he draws a "HJK"

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With instructions, the common practice is to use the present tense when listing a series of events:

> To start the motor: *open* the fuel valve, *hold down* the igniter button, and *pull* the starting cord.

The exception is when describing previous action in relation to the current action, but you should use the present perfect rather than the simple past:

> If Player One *has started* an attack, Player Two must respond immediately or forfeit his turn.

Of course, there are situations where the simple past or past perfect might be justified, but in general, imagine you are describing the action *as the game is being played* and use the simple present.